# Redmine 2.0.0 plugin install error ActionController::RoutingError uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have install Redmine 2.0.0 and try to Install plugin in **plugins** directory from github.
I had try to install two plugins **Monitoring_Controlling** and **Redmine-Bulk-User-Assignments** follow the installation steps written on github plugin but in both plugin getting same error and error is following

```
Started GET "/bulk_user_assignments" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat May 19 13:37:26 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant BulkUserAssignmentsController):
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in `constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  rack-openid (1.3.1) lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__108590059__call__4__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6
```

Do I need to do anything else to install plugins in redmine 2 or write routes any other place.
One more thing both the plugin is written in rails 2 so I change the routes file to rails 3 routes file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine Monitoring Controlling Plugin is ready to Redmine 2.0.

Check last commit on git repository: https://github.com/alexmonteiro/Redmine-Monitoring-Controlling

Answer (score 3):

Plugins based on Redmine 1.x will break on 2.0

See the redmine2.0 release news --> http://www.redmine.org/news/66

The monitoring_controlling plugin is not Redmine2.0 compatible yet(unlilke advertised) and I have opened up an issue here --> 
https://github.com/alexmonteiro/Redmine-Monitoring-Controlling/issues/17#issuecomment-5806223

You need to change the Route files(one of the changes). More for understanding the general scope of writing future proof plugin, this discussion might be of some use -->

http://www.redmine.org/issues/10813

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I found monitoring and controlling is compatible for redmine2.0.x on [this link](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/monitoring-controlling).
And can you please explain what other changes should I make to install plugin. I made one change in route file what others?

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote in the post?? The plugin is not compatible! Its a mistake for which I have opened up an issue. For you other question go through the last link. Atleast read the answer posts before commenting!